# Notation for a special type of function / differential operator

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, notation

I'm working with functions $f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ that have the following representation
\begin{align*}
f(x) = [f_1(x_1), \dots, f_m(x_m)]^T,
\end{align*}
with $f_i :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \in C^\infty$ for all $i = 1, \dots, m$. At the moment I'm using $f'$ to denote 
\begin{align*}
f'(x) = [f_1'(x_1), \dots, f_m'(x_m)]^T,
\end{align*}
where $f_i'$ is simply the first derivative of $f_i$. However, I feel that this notation is a bit confusing. Is there some commonly used alternative, or should I stick with $f'$?

Comment: If you assume $f \colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ then $f_i$ is, for any $i = 1, \ldots, m$, a function from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  What do you understand under $f'_i$?

Comment: In this case the $f_i$ only take the $i$-th element of $x$ as input. An example would be
$$f(x) = f(x_1, x_2) = [\sin(x_1), \exp(x_2)]^T$$.
Therefore $f'_1 = \cos$.

Comment: The derivative $Df$ of $f$ equals then $\mathrm{diag}(f'_1, \ldots, f'_m)$.  One can denote the vector consisting of the diagonal entries of that matrix by $f'$, but to me such notation would be rather nonstandard.